# Expanding a data.frame by replacing missing values with set of all possible values in R

Tags: r

I want to expand my dataset by replacing each incomplete row with the set of all possible rows. Does anyone have any suggestions for an efficient way to do this?

For example, suppose X and Z can each take values 0 or 1.

Input:

```
   id y  x  z
 1  1 0  0 NA
 2  2 1 NA  0
 3  3 0  1  1
 4  4 1 NA NA
```

Output:

```
  id y x z
1  1 0 0 0
2  1 0 0 1
3  2 1 0 0
4  2 1 1 0
5  3 0 1 1
6  4 1 0 0
7  4 1 0 1
8  4 1 1 0
9  4 1 1 1
```

At the moment I just work through the original dataset row by row:

```
for(i in 1:N){

if(is.na(temp.dat$x[i]) & !is.na(temp.dat$z[i])){
    augment <- matrix(rep(temp.dat[i,],2),ncol=ncol(temp.dat),byrow=TRUE)
    augment[,3] <- c(0,1)
}else
if(!is.na(temp.dat$x[i]) & is.na(temp.dat$z[i])){
    augment <- matrix(rep(temp.dat[i,],2),ncol=ncol(temp.dat),byrow=TRUE)
    augment[,4] <- c(0,1)
}else{
if(is.na(temp.dat$x[i]) & is.na(temp.dat$z[i])){
    augment <- matrix(rep(temp.dat[i,],4),ncol=ncol(temp.dat),byrow=TRUE)
    augment[,3] <- c(0,0,1,1)
    augment[,4] <- c(0,1,0,1)
}
}
```

Comment: What is your approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try by

1. Creating an "indx" of count of "NAs" in each row (`rowSums(is.na(...)`)
2. Use the "indx" to expand the rows of the original dataset (`df[rep(1:nrow...`)
3. Loop over (`sapply`) the "indx" and use that as "times" argument in `rep`, and do `expand.grid` of values `0,1` to create the "lst"
4. `split` the expanded dataset, "df1", by "id"
5. Use `Map` to change corresponding "NA" values in "lst2" by the values in "lst"
6. `rbind` the list elements

   ```
   indx <- rowSums(is.na(df[-1]))
   df1 <- df[rep(1:nrow(df), 2^indx),]
   lst <- sapply(indx, function(x) expand.grid(rep(list(0:1), x)))
   lst2 <- split(df1, df1$id)
   res <- do.call(rbind,Map(function(x,y) {x[is.na(x)] <- as.matrix(y);x},
                             lst2, lst))
   row.names(res) <- NULL
   res
   #  id y x z
   #1  1 0 0 0
   #2  1 0 0 1
   #3  2 1 0 0
   #4  2 1 1 0
   #5  3 0 1 1
   #6  4 1 0 0
   #7  4 1 1 0
   #8  4 1 0 1
   #9  4 1 1 1
   ```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(id = 1:4, y = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), x = c(0L, NA, 
1L, NA), z = c(NA, 0L, 1L, NA)), .Names = c("id", "y", "x", "z"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4"))
```